# Delete database data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When I put this link on the browser it will worked. But, When clicked on the button it will not working. What is the wrong in this code.
http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shopCartProductDelete.php?cart_ID=6

```js
$scope.delete = function(cart_ID, index) {
var params = $.param({"cart_ID":cart_ID});

  console.log(cart_ID);
  $http({
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    url: 'http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shopCartProductDelete.php?cart_ID=$cart_ID',
    method: "GET",
    data: params
  }).success(function(data){
    $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
  });
}
```

```html
<img src="img/removecart.png" ng-click="delete({{produ.cart_ID}}, $index)" style="max-height: 40px;margin-right: 15px;"/>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","look4com_lk");
if(isset($_GET['cart_ID'])){
$cart_ID = $_GET['cart_ID'];
$res = "DELETE FROM l4wlk_cart WHERE cart_ID='".$cart_ID."'";
mysqli_query($con, $res);


}

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside angular directives you don't need to parse the angular value. You should change this

```
<img src="img/removecart.png" ng-click="delete({{produ.cart_ID}}, $index)" style="max-height: 40px;margiurln-right: 15px;"/>
```

to

```
<img src="img/removecart.png" ng-click="delete(produ.cart_ID, $index)" style="max-height: 40px;margin-right: 15px;"/>
```

**Update**

Try to change your js code as below

```
$http.get('http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shopCartProductDelete.php', {"cart_ID":cart_ID})
.success(function(data){
   $scope.data.splice(index, 1);
});
```

Just check with

```
if(isset($_GET['cart_ID'])){
  $cart_ID = $_GET['cart_ID'];
  $res = "DELETE FROM l4wlk_cart WHERE cart_ID='".$cart_ID."'";
  mysqli_query($con, $res) or mysqli_error($con);
}else{
  die("Param value not set up");
}
```

Comment: I changed like this `ng-click="delete(produ.cart_ID, $index)"` but this is not work.

Comment: try console log in controller `produ.cart_ID`. Share the value

Comment: When I add this code `console.log(cart_ID)` cart ID will display. java script code has any error.

Comment: Make sure you're getting param value in PHP. print `$_GET` in PHP and see

Comment: not working `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/youtubewebservice/shopCartProductDelete.php. Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` I have like this error before we started.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122079/discussion-between-drk-and-vineet).

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) of `ng-click`

[image]

**It uses an `expression`.**

If `template` was written in the `Type` column, then you would have written those values in double curly braces `{{..}}`. But since it accepts an expression, so there's no need to use double curly braces.

Change your `<img..>` to:

```
<img src="img/removecart.png" ng-click="delete(produ.cart_ID, $index)" style="max-height: 40px;margin-right: 15px;"/>
```

Comment: I changed like this `ng-click="delete(produ.cart_ID, $index)"` but this is not work.

Answer (score -1):

instead of doing `console.log(cart_ID)` please check the value of `console.log(produ.cart_ID)`

Comment: `console.log(produ.cart_ID)` used this. Then will display error like this. `Can't find variable: produ`

Comment: you are trying to delete produ.cart_Id and you have your cart_id valu in Cart_Id try delete(Cart_Id,$index)